# Can I use Tiff's pyramids to set them as source image

Tags: wpf, libtiff

I am developing app that loads, zooms and pans large Tiff image (~1.7GB). I use Image control System.Windows.Controls.Image to show the image. It load and shows, but zooming is very slow, so i decided I should use(and comute) the pyramids.

I have found that LibTiff is a good solution when it comes to large Tiff files. 
I've read the documentation, but couldn't find out how to use image pyramids.

What is the best workaround to set the pyramids as image source?

P.S. I'm new to WPF